# Why is the Republican Party going along with Trump's legal challenges to the election results?

Tags: united-states, election, donald-trump

From most reports, the Trump campaign's legal challenges to the presidential vote counting process have little merit (several have already been thrown out by the courts) and a practically negligible chance to swing the election in his favor.

But many high level Republicans, including Mitch McConnell and Lindsey Graham, are going along with him. They must know that this is a fruitless endeavor. And since Trump is going to be out of office soon, they no longer need to kowtow to him.

Why are Republican party leaders letting him get away with this? Does the GOP actually gain any political value from it? Or do they just not have the power to rein him in and get him to concede graciously?

Comment: Please don't try to answer the question using comments. If you would like to answer, please post a real answer which adheres to our quality standards.

Answer (score 4):

> And since Trump is going to be out of office soon, they no longer need to kowtow to him.
>
> Why are Republican party leaders letting him get away with this? Does the GOP actually gain any political value from it? Or do they just not have the power to rein him in and get him to concede graciously?

Because they need his voters - the 2020 election had the [second highest turnout of any US election in the last *century*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/2020/elections/voter-turnout/), and that's in very large part due to Trump. He's a massively polarising figure, of course, and that resulted in huge numbers of people a) trying to turf him out and b) trying to keep him in. The former group succeeded in this election, but there are further elections to come in which the Republican Party will need people who voted for Trump or else risk being overwhelmed by a continuing high turnout for the Democrats.

The most imminent threat (and a very major one for the Republican party) is the January 2021 run-offs in Georgia, which will determine which party holds a majority in the Senate - if the Republicans lose those then the Democrats will hold all legislative and executive authority for a minimum of two years; that's not a risk the party is going to take. Remember that although Trump won't be on the actual ballot, *he'll still be in power* when those elections are run. The Trump effect is notoriously hard to predict, but I think it's a pretty solid guess that he'll still have the same effect of drawing out Democrat voters, particularly if he spends the next two months trying to keep hold of power. If the Republicans spend the next two months showing less than total support for Trump then his base is going to be less and less enthused about coming out to vote for them; especially when he's not on the ticket.